# What do I have here? API or Web Service

Tags: api, rest, web-services, soap, django-rest-framework

I have a project for Master's Degree: **design and implementation of web services for an elearning platform.**

Now, I know that there are two main architectures for web services: **SOAP, and REST**

Now, I wanted to use REST architecture, so normally I would have something called "RESTful web services", **so I started development with Django and Django Rest Framework**

Now, this is the part where I get confused, **Is this an API or Web Services**

If it is an API, then how can I develop RESTful Web Services?

If it is both, please explain more if you could.

I'm very confused about this, and each time I try to understand, I get more confused, Please can someone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 0):

An application programming interface (API) allows you to interact with a component, system, or resource. It's a very broad concept. To understand it, the emphasis should be placed on the word [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)):

> In computing, an interface is a shared boundary across which two or more separate components of a computer system exchange information. The exchange can be between software, computer hardware, peripheral devices, humans, and combinations of these.

When you need something from a component or you want it to do something for you, you don't just go in it and do it yourself, you "ask it" for that something or for that action by interfacing with it. The interface of the component says what it can do for you or what you can invoke from the component.

In regards to web services, you have to understand that a web service is in fact an API, because it's an interface with some component (in this case whatever is behind the web service itself: it can be a database, an application, a system, etc).

Like I said, an API is a very broad term. When you say web service, you are adding some restrictions to that term. For example, a web service is invoked over the network. Not all APIs are like this. Some API's can be exposed as libraries, or frameworks that you call directly from your code as methods or functions. So all web services are APIs, but not all APIs are web services.

If you want to build a web service, you can implement it with REST or with SOAP. There is a difference between the two (REST is an architectural style, while SOAP is a protocol), but as concepts they work the same: they provide an interface with which to interact over the network, i.e. an API. But since you are using Django, thus Python, I suggest you go the REST way, not SOAP (support for SOAP in Python isn't all that great).